# Error Decrypting of path string in c# .net

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption

I have a windows application that needs to store windows path in the database. 
Example: `C:\Folder 1\Folder 2\ Folder 3\Folder 4\Folder 5\Folder 6\Folder 7\Folder 8\Folder 9\Folder 10\File.txt`

But before saving, I need to encrypt it first for security purposes.

Here is my Encrypt method:

```
 private static string Encrypt<T>(string value, string password)
            where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{

    byte[] vectorBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_vector);
    byte[] saltBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_salt);
    byte[] valueBytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);

    byte[] encrypted;
    using (T cipher = new T())
    {
        PasswordDeriveBytes _passwordBytes =
            new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, _hash, _iterations);
        byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);

        cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = cipher.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
        {
            using (MemoryStream to = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream writer = new CryptoStream(to, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    writer.Write(valueBytes, 0, valueBytes.Length);
                    writer.FlushFinalBlock();
                    encrypted = to.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        cipher.Clear();
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
}
```

After that, the system decrypting it for display. Here is my decryption method:

```
private static string Decrypt<T>(string value, string password) where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    byte[] vectorBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_vector);
    byte[] saltBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_salt);
    byte[] valueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

    byte[] decrypted;
    int decryptedByteCount = 0;

    using (T cipher = new T())
    {
        PasswordDeriveBytes _passwordBytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, _hash, _iterations);
        byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);

        cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        try
        {
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
            {
                using (MemoryStream from = new MemoryStream(valueBytes))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream reader = new CryptoStream(from, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        decrypted = new byte[valueBytes.Length];
                        decryptedByteCount = reader.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        cipher.Clear();
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted, 0, decryptedByteCount);
}
```

But the system keeps on throwing error:

> "The input is not a valid Base-64 string".

I don't know if it is because the path string is too long? or is it because of spaces? So what I did was upon calling encrypt and decrypt,I'm calling `HttpUtility.UrlKeyValueEncode and HttpUtility.UrlKeyValueDecode`:

```
public string Encryption(string stringToEncrypt)
{
    return HttpUtility.UrlKeyValueEncode(Encrypt(stringToEncrypt));
}


public string Decryption(string stringToDecrypt)
{
    return Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlKeyValueDecode(stringToDecrypt));
}
```

This works on me. BUT, when my path has '-' character, same problem occurs. Sample path: `C:\Folder 1 - copy\Folder 2 - copy\ Folder 3 - copy\Folder 4 - copy\Folder 5 - copy\Folder 6 - copy\Folder 7 - copy\Folder 8 - copy\Folder 9 - copy\Folder 10 - copy\File.txt`

What went wrong?

Comment: Is it a '-' or an unicode '-'? :) Try using UTF8 encoding instead of ASCII encoding.

Comment: Curious as to why you encrypt the path and not the file?

Comment: So that, user can open it in the explorer

Comment: And it can be downloaded from the sharepoint also. Through that path. Wherein if it is existing, it will just overwrite it